# Zero divison in R

Tags: r

Is there an easy way of avoiding 0 division error in R. Specifically,

```
a <- c(1,0,2,0)
b <- c(3,2,1,0)
sum(b/a)
```

This code gives an error due to division by zero. 
I would like a way to define anything/0 = 0 so that this kind of operation would still be valid.

Answer (score 18):

Well, let's back up a minute.  R does NOT return an error.  It quite correctly returns NaN.  You had better have a darn good reason for rejecting NaN values in your work.  Why do you allow any `b` element to be zero in the first place?  You need to think about what your code is really intended to do,  and what it means (statistically, say) to cheerfully throw away all the cases where `b[j]==0` .

Answer (score 11):

What is you set all items in the denominator to 0 to `NA` and then exclude `NA`? in your `sum`?

```
a[a==0] <- NA
sum(b/a, na.rm=TRUE)
#-----
[1] 3.5
```

Or without modifying `a`: `sum(b/ifelse(a==0,NA,a), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: or `sum(ifelse(a==0, 0, b/a))`

Comment: Comparing numbers to 0 using == works for integers, but is risky for floating point numbers. See the R FAQ 7.31 on this. Better to use something like `abs(c(1,0,2,1e-9))<1e-6` to avoid running afoul of machine accuracy issues.

Answer (score 9):

You could change the function "/" to have an exception for zero:

```
"/" <- function(x,y) ifelse(y==0,0,base:::"/"(x,y))
```

For example:

```
> 10/0
[1] 0
```

This is very risky though, for example it might break other people's code. If you want to do this it is probably a good idea to assign a different operator rather than changing `/`. Also it makes mathematically no sense!

Comment: Geez, Sacha, you pretty much downvoted yourself w/ that last sentence :-)

Comment: I don't care about downvotes at all, but I don't really see why I get one here for giving the exact answer to the question posed.

Comment: It wasn't me.  My guess is someone is paranoid about overloading operators :-(

Answer (score 7):

If you want to mask all the `NaN` and `Inf` results, try something like:

```
a <- c(1,0,2,0)
b <- c(3,2,1,0)
result <- b/a
sum(result[is.finite(result)])
[1] 3.5
```

Or all in one line:

```
sum((b/a)[is.finite(b/a)])
[1] 3.5
```

Answer (score 6):

I just worked on similar situation.
This works well with ifelse():

```
sum(ifelse(a==0,0,b/a))
```